# Multiple selects into same result

Tags: sql

In SQL server, how can I bring in the result of multiple SELECT statements into a single returned result? I am running the COUNT with various criteria and want to be able to display them all in one result. Is this possible or would I need SSRS?

Here are my SQL queries:

```
--Total calls in the queue
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Total calls in the queue'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE
Status not in( 'Closed', 'Pending Close', 'Pending Resolution')
AND 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
GROUP by ItemOwner

--Total new calls for the week
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Total calls in the queue'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND
CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-7, GetDate())), 0) 
GROUP by ItemOwner

--Calls fixed within SLA for the week
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Calls fixed within SLA for the week'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND
CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-7, GetDate())), 0) 
AND
Status = 'Closed'
AND SLAStage = 'Meets'
GROUP by ItemOwner

--Calls fixed outside SLA for the week
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Calls fixed outside SLA for the week'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND
CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-7, GetDate())), 0) 
AND
Status = 'Closed'
AND SLAStage = 'Escalation 2'
GROUP by ItemOwner

--Calls older than 7 days
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Calls older than 7 days'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE
Status not in( 'Closed', 'Pending Close', 'Pending Resolution')
AND 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND 
CreatedDateTime <= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-7, GetDate())), 0) 
GROUP by ItemOwner

--Calls older than 14 days
SELECT 
ItemOwner as 'Team'
, Count (*) as 'Calls older than 14 days'
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE
Status not in( 'Closed', 'Pending Close', 'Pending Resolution')
AND 
SLAStage is not NULL
AND 
Priority not in( '7')
AND
ItemOwner in('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND 
CreatedDateTime <= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-14, GetDate())), 0) 
GROUP by ItemOwner
```

Ultimately I want the results to look something like this:

```
Team    Active  Opened in last 7 days   Resolved inside SLA in last 7 days  Resolved outside SLA in last 7 days Older than 7 days   Older than 14 days
 482         83      83     197     2      34      23
1041         22      22      58     0      12       8
 483         68      68      50     0      46      35
 486         13      13      25     0       6       2
 489         38      38      2      3      31      30
 701         12      12      3      0       9       9
1714        270     270     31      0     251     239
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've added more detail into my original ask. I hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  For instance the first two queries turn into this one query:

```
SELECT ItemOwner as Team,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status not in ('Closed', 'Pending Close', 'Pending Resolution') AND
                     ItemOwner in ('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as total_calls_in_queue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ItemOwner in ('482', '1041', '483', '486', '489', '701', '1714')
AND
                     CreatedDateTime >= CAST(DATEADD(day -7, GetDate()) as DATE)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as total_calls_in_queue
FROM CG_IncidentRequest
WHERE SLAStage is not NULL AND 
      Priority not in ( '7')
GROUP by ItemOwner;
```

The rest of the queries follow the same pattern.

Notes and advice:

- Do not use single quotes to define column aliases.  Eventually, you'll start using single quotes when you use the column, and that'll be a bug.  Either name the columns so they don't need to be escaped, or use double quotes or square braces.
- Write out the date parts for the date functions.  "dd" may seem obvious for "day", but "mm"?  "y"?  "dw"?  Be nice and make the code as transparent as feasible.
- You can just cast to date to remove the time component in SQL Server 2008 and beyond.
- If `ItemOwner` and/or `Priority` are numbers, don't use single quotes for the constants.  This confuses human readers of the query and can confuse the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you need is a UNION statement. UNION takes the results of multiple SELECTS and returns them as one result set. Note, however, that each of the SELECTS must return the same number of columns and, I believe, that the column names returned in each SELECT must must have the same name.

Comment: I believe some results may not return any data, if the criteria has not been met. Can you take another look at my ask, now that I've added my SQL I'm using?

Comment: @Ben Actually, in most databases only the first select in a UNION is used for the names in the result. For the other select's no aliases are required.

Comment: I fail to see how a union will put these aggregate numbers into columns like the OP appears to be asking. You could start there, I guess, but you'd still have to pivot it. I think either Gordon's answer or putting each count into a correlated subquery are the most direct ways of creating this query.

Comment: @TimLehner  I think you're right, Tim. The original question didn't present the sample data or desired results and simply asked how to append the results of multiple SELECT statements to each other.